# Conditional enum list according to value of another property mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm working on mongoose schema and trying to create an address object which includes enum for countries and cities, city's enum needs to be changed depending on selected country like code snippet below. How could I do that?

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
  address: { 
    country:{ 
      type: String, 
      enum:['USA', 'GB', 'CA', 'BR' ....] 
     }, 
    city:{ 
      type: String,
      enum:[...cities[`${country}]] 
     } 
  }
}) 
 const cities ={ 
    USA :['New York', 'Los Angeles'...], 
    GB :['London', 'Manchester'...] 
    }
```

Comment: I don't think MongoDB supports this out of box. What I would consider doing is to have a `pre save` hook to check if a city belongs to the country you are updating.

Comment: thank you for pointing out hooks. I've used pre validate hook since I am trying to validate string value with enum rather than setting some value. It works now.